# Not able to get True result for same Values in Codeigniter (PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to compare two values in Codeigniter but the result is always false even if the values and type are same.
I'm using this piece of code in CodeIgniter.
Below code.

```
$return_name = $this->db->get('feegroup');
$data = $return_name->result();
foreach($data as $d)
{
    $name = $d->name;
    if(($name) === ($this->input->post("name")))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error_message',"Sorry cannot create $name fee group, you cannot have two similar fee groups. Either edit or delete $name fee group or change name to create a new fee group.");
        redirect(base_url("feegroup/add"));
    }#EOF IF
}#EOF foreach
```

I have used trim(), strlen(), is_string() to view the result it shows true everytime but while comparing same data it returns false.

If values from DB comes **Sample** and If users types **sample** it returns false but If values from DB comes **Sample** and If users type **Sample** it returns True
It is not checking the Case.

For example:

1     Parent === Parent  =      True

2     Parent ===  parent    =    False

3     Parent ===  Sam      =     False

4     Sam  ===    sam    =       False

5     heLLO  ===  hello    =     False

Comment: do you want that ` Parent === parent` returns `true` ?

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui : Yes dear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
if(strcasecmp($name,$this->input->post("name")) === 0)
```

Comment: It did work but Why it is not working the way I was doing it.

Comment: === checks whether  both are identical and you can't use ==  it is case sensitive

Answer (score 3):

you use `strtolower` function to convert text into lower case and its compare proper

```
if(strtolower($name) === strtolower($this->input->post("name")))
```